# Find file is including library files in Intellij/Pycharm: how to choose only the locally created ones?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Until now `Intellij` and `Pycharm` were behaving as I had expected when looking for files. Let's talk about `setup.py` - for which there are two of them created in our project. Now when looking for that file via "Find files" is bringing up anything and everything in the existing `python` libraries.

I was looking for maybe a `Search in directories` or something else to filter out the libraries. How can this be done - so that only

[image]